# AWS Elasticsearch access via nodejs using credentials

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I have been accessing my AWS elastic search server from my ec2 instance using this code as my ec2 instance had IAM role access.

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const client = new Client({ node: https://some_elasticsearch_endpoint.xxxxxx });
```

Now, we are moving and making sure that they are accessible via secret keys.

What do I do to generate a client object using `@elastic/elasticsearch` npm module to access the ES server with AWS creds?

Thanks